# Webpack config in sub folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

How do I need to configure webpack-dev-server's `devServer.contentBase` when the webpack config is in a subfolder?

Directory structure:

```
-config
-- webpack.config.dev.js
- dist
- src
- index.js
- package.json
```

`webpack.config.dev.js` (in `config` directory):

```js
// Configure output directory
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/../dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'
},

// Configure webpack-dev-server
devServer: {
    contentBase: ???,
    port: 3000
},
```

Put simple, my webpack configuration file is in the `config` directory, but I want all output to be in the `dist` directory.

Problem is that when I set `contentBase: __dirname + '/../dist'`, it says `Cannot GET /`.

Comment: try a relative url for your contentBase  ....   rm the leading "/"

Comment: Remove it from where?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **path.join** to get your path correctly evaluated.

```
devServer: {
contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../../dist'),
port: 3000,
hot: true,
},
```

Refer https://github.com/anandgupta193/react-enterprise-starter-kit for correct implementation.

Note: The starter-kit referred above contains all webpack related files inside webpack/*, so path may vary if you have webpack.config file in your root directory.

Answer (score 0):

This set of options is picked up by webpack-dev-server and can be used to change its behavior in various ways. Here's a simple example that serves everything from dist/ directory in the project root:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
},
```